# Nicaragua on arrival visa for Indians having valid Schengen visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, nicaragua

I want to travel to Nicaragua from India and I have a valid Schengen visa.

Will they give me an on arrival visa via hotel booking?

Comment: I'm confused, what has the Schengen visa to do with all this?

Comment: Somebody told me that if u have schenegen visa u will get on arrival visa at airport

Comment: Okay thanks sir i will made it confirm wi nicaragua embassy

Answer (score 4):

According to TIMATIC (courtesy [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm)):

> / 06NOV16 / 1235 UTC
>
> National India (IN)             /Embarkation India (IN) Destination
>   Nicaragua (NI)
>
> Nicaragua (NI)
>
> Passport required. 
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.   Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with a machine-readable (ICAO 9303 compliant) temporary passport.
>
> Visa Issuance:
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of normal passports issued to
>   nationals of India can obtain a visa on arrival for a max. stay of 30
>   days. Fee: USD 50.-: 
>    - applicable to holders of a valid visa issued by Canada, the USA or a Schengen Member.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - All visitors are required to obtain a Tourist Card on arrival. Fee: USD 10.-:
> - Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay and documents required for their next destination.
>
>   -exempt are unaccompanied minors.
> - Extension possible. Fee: USD 2.- per day of stay.
>
> Warning:
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

So yes, you may obtain a visa on arrival.